# Lists within a list

Tags: punctuation, lists

Here's my list:
Violin, Piano, Reading Music, Dancing: Musical Theater, Swing, Break, Contra, Ballet (beginner,) Singing: Tenor, Conversational Spanish, Card Tricks, Parkour, Biking, Hiking, Rock Climbing, Camping, Archery, Shooting Sports, Boating: Canoe, Motorboat, Sailboat, Kayak, Whitewater Raft, Scuba

I would normally separate this list by commas, but within the list "dancing," "singing," and "boating" have specifics listed. It seems like I should use a semicolon to delineate the fact that I don't sing in conversational Spanish, just using commas makes this confusing.  The fact that "dancing" and "boating" have actual lists following them and "singing" only has one word and not a list further complicates my dilemma.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Don't do it that way!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because how to organise a list is not restricted to the English language.

Answer (score 1):

If it's being written your best bet is to use new lines, and possibly headings. This would make your lists/sublists much more differentiateable. You can probably consider Singing to be part of your Music list.

> Music: Violin, Piano, Reading Music, Singing (Tenor)
>
> Dancing: Musical Theater, Swing, Break, Contra, Ballet (beginner)
>
> Outdoors: Parkour, Biking, Hiking, Rock Climbing, Camping, Archery,
>   Shooting Sports
>
> Boating: Canoe, Motorboat, Sailboat, Kayak, Whitewater Raft, Scuba
>
> Other: Conversational Spanish, Card Tricks

Alternatively you can use semicolons between lists

I like to eat fruit: apples, oranges; vegetables: celery, avocados, cucumber.

Comment: Perhaps also consider bullets or sub-bullet points.

Comment: I tried bullets, but my space is limited.

Comment: I also like the idea of making categories (aslum's suggestion) and with a little tweaking was able to fit it into my limited space. Thanks everyone!